# append a user specified suffix to the output of cat command

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to append a user specified suffix to the end of a file based on certain condition specified beforehand. I have the filenames stored in a file called *changedfile.txt* . I am executing the following command to get filename without any extension code.

```
cat changedfile.txt | cut -d "." -f1
```

I want to add a user provided suffix before the extension.
For example : If the output of the previous command was `a/b/c.toml`, and the user provided suffix is `_backup`, I want my final file to be renamed from `a/b/c.toml` to `a/b/c_backup.toml`. I have a for loop to handle the changing user suffix. I need a way to append the suffix to the file.

I thought something like this would work( thought += appends strings).

```
cat changedfile.txt | cut -d "." -f1 +backup
                   or
cat changedfile.txt | cut -d "." -f1 +=backup
```

got this error (`cut: +backup: No such file or directory`). I can understand why that command doesn't work.

Would appreciate if someone can get this working. For now even if there was a way to get it working for one suffix it's fine.I am using bash 3.2 .

Comment: Check https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano He's not renaming a file, he's processing the contents of a file.

Comment: Yes, confusing "... want my final file to be renamed..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cut` just outputs the selected field, it can't make changes. You would need to pipe to some other tool to append something.

But you don't want to append, you want to insert in the middle of the line. You can do that entirely with `sed`.

```
sed 's/\./_backup./' changedfile.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the output of sed to just a line instead of the whole file ? I would like to have different suffices for different files. I have a variable which will dynamically get the required suffix name.

Comment: `sed -n 's/\./_backup./p' changedfile.txt` The `-n` option prevents printing every line by default, and `p` prints the changed line.